# Multiple custom JPanels inside JScrollPane - resizing/showing components on one resizes them all

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jscrollpane

So I've got a custom JPanel which I use multiple instances of to fill a wrapper Panel inside a JScrollPane.  The number of custom JPanel elements I use is dependent on the size of a list.  The problem I'm running across is a part of my Custom JPanel has another invisible JPanel which expands when I click on it's parent.  The behavior I'm trying to mimic is that of an accordian UI element.  Before I was on this project I was primarily a webdev and while I have worked with Java a lot, I'm still relatively new to Swing.

Here is an example of the behavior - the scroll pane with all elements closed.  (forgive me for the quick paint-job comments.  I tried to emphasize what I see going wrong).

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wk90N.png]

Next, is the image of the first element expanded - which unexpectedly expands all other elements.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9n3t.png]

It must be noted that I'm only targeting the first panel and setting the visibility, yet all other repeating panels length grows when I do this, but obviously the components inside stay invisible.

Finally, here is my final deired result:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvSjn.png]

Is there some sort of constraint in the JScrollPane that resizes it's child JPanel's components to retain the same height at all times?  I can't seem to figure a way around this and I've played with all sorts of different wrappers and layouts, all to no avail.

Please let me know if anyone wants to see code snippets, but they'll have to be heavily redacted and stripped down due to the nature of the project.

Thanks,
Marek

PS: yes, I absolutely must use Swing.

Edit: Here is a static, quick and dirty, stripped down implementation of my code as suggested by Roddy of the Frozen Peas

ExampleScrollPane:

```
public class ExampleSrollPane extends JPanel {
private static ExampleSrollPane instance = null;
private JScrollPane contentScrollPanel = new JScrollPane();
private Vector<ExamplePanel> exPanels;
private JPanel wrapPanel = new JPanel();

public ExampleSrollPane() {
    super();
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED, Color.white,
            Color.white, new Color(115, 114, 105), new Color(165, 163, 151)));

    exPanels = new Vector<ExamplePanel>();
    init();
}

private void init() {

    contentScrollPanel.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    contentScrollPanel.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    contentScrollPanel.setBorder(new CompoundBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5), new SoftBevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED)));
    this.add(contentScrollPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    initPanels();
}

public void initPanels() {
    int numUnits = 15;
    // Init one empty panel at least
    if (numUnits == 0) numUnits = 15;
    wrapPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(numUnits, 1));

    for (int i = 0; i < numUnits; i++) {
        ExamplePanel exPan = new ExamplePanel(i);
        exPanels.add(i, exPan);
        wrapPanel.add(exPan);
    }
    contentScrollPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(575, 100));
    contentScrollPanel.getViewport().add(wrapPanel);
}
/**
 * Method: viewPanel()
 *
 */
private static void viewPanel() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.add(getInstance());
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setSize(new Dimension(600, 350));
    frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static ExampleSrollPane getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new ExampleSrollPane();
    }
    return instance;
}
/**
 * The main method.
 * 
 * @param args the arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            viewPanel();
        }
    });
}
```

}

It's here in the showHideTable method which creates the problem.

ExamplePanel (my custom JPanel):

```
public class ExamplePanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private static final Border STAT_BORDER = BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED, Color.white,
        Color.white, new Color(115, 114, 105), new Color(165, 163, 151));

public static final EmptyBorder PAD_BORDER = new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10);

public int indx;
private JLabel unitLabel;
private JLabel statLabel;
private JLabel invLabel;
private JLabel targetLabel;
private JLabel timeLabel;

// Custom BasicArrowButton to expand/hide the "table"
private UnitToggleButton unitToggleButton;
// The expandable JPanel
public ExpanableTable elementTable;

private String id;
private String unitStatusString;
private String invStatusString;
private String targetString;
private String timeString;

public Color componentColor;

private JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
public JPanel tablePanel = new JPanel();

public ExamplePanel(int index) {
    super();
    this.indx = index;
    id = "Unit # 00000";
    id = "Unit #00000";
    unitStatusString = "PENDING";
    invStatusString = "PENDING";
    elementTable = new ExpanableTable();
    targetString = "AZ501";
    timeString = "11:18:27";
    componentColor = this.getBackground();
    init();

}

private void init() {
    topPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    topPanel.setBorder(PAD_BORDER);

    unitLabel = new JLabel(id); // TODO unit.getID();
    statLabel = new JLabel(unitStatusString); // TODO: unit.getStatus();
    invLabel = new JLabel(invStatusString); // TODO: unit.getInventoryStatus();

    targetLabel = new JLabel(targetString);
    timeLabel = new JLabel(timeString);

    buildLabel(statLabel);
    buildLabel(invLabel);
    buildLabel(targetLabel);
    buildLabel(timeLabel);

    unitToggleButton = new UnitToggleButton(BasicArrowButton.EAST, indx);

    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_END;
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    gbc.weightx = .1;
    gbc.weighty = 1;
    gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);

    // Add toggle button far-left, row 1
    topPanel.add(unitToggleButton, gbc);

    // Add empty space far-left, row 2
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    topPanel.add(new JLabel("     "), gbc);

    // Add unit label row 1 column 2
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.weightx = .3;
    topPanel.add(unitLabel, gbc);

    // Add Status label row 1 column 3
    gbc.gridx = 2;
    topPanel.add(statLabel, gbc);

    // Add inventory label row 1 column 4
    gbc.gridx = 3;
    topPanel.add(invLabel, gbc);

    // Add tasking label row 2 column 2
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    topPanel.add(new JLabel("   Tasking: "), gbc);

    // Add target label row 2 column 3
    gbc.gridx = 2;
    topPanel.add(targetLabel, gbc);

    // Add mission Label row 2 column 4
    gbc.gridx = 3;
    topPanel.add(timeLabel, gbc);

    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 2;
    gbc.weighty = 1;
    gbc.weightx = 1;
    gbc.gridwidth = 4;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
    JSeparator sep = new JSeparator(JSeparator.HORIZONTAL);
    topPanel.add(sep, gbc);

    gbc.gridy = 3;
    topPanel.add(elementTable, gbc);
    revalidate();

    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    this.add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    this.add(tablePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    HSIUtils.setColoredBorder(tablePanel, Color.RED);
    tablePanel.add(elementTable);

    // Do NOT show the table on initialization
    tablePanel.setVisible(false);
    unitToggleButton.addActionListener(this);
}

/**
 * Method: buildLabel()
 *
 * @param label
 */
private void buildLabel(JLabel label) {
    label.setBorder(STAT_BORDER);
    label.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(80, 20));
    label.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 25));
    label.setOpaque(true);
    label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    label.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    label.setBackground(componentColor);
}

private void showHideTable(boolean show) {
    tablePanel.setVisible(!show);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == this.unitToggleButton) {
        showHideTable(unitToggleButton.isExpanded());
    }

}
```

}

ExpandableTable:

```
public class ExpanableTable extends JPanel {

    public ExpanableTable () {
        super();
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(new JButton("Test1"), BorderLayout.WEST);
        add(new JButton("Test2"), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(new JButton("Test3"), BorderLayout.EAST);
    }
}
```

Basically I want to be able expand/show/resize each Panel inside the scroll pane independently of the others.  As it currently stands, if I show a hidden Panel on one, the other panel's height grows to match but does not show the component.  Very strange to me but could be my ignorance of certain Swing components and the constraints they contain.

Comment: You should prepare a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (minimal, complete,viable example) showing your issue. Then we can help you get your minimum example working as you need it, and you can adapt it to your actual code base.

Comment: Tossed together a quick n' dirty MCVE.  Thanks for the suggestion and hope that helps.

Comment: `Tossed together a quick n' dirty MCVE` - it is not an "MCVE" 1) there are no imports. 2) you are missing classes. I gave up trying to get it to compile, so all I can do is give a best guess answer.

Comment: I marked your answer as the correct one. Forgive me for not including imports and classes I was forced to hide.  I threw together quick and dirty snippets, which I figured someone could extrapolate my issue from, which you did below.  I'll be sure and use the correct terminology in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there some sort of constraint in the JScrollPane that resizes it's child JPanel's components to retain the same height at all times?

A scroll pane doesn't resize anything. It only displays the component added to the scroll panes and add scroll bars when the preferred size of the component added is greater than the size of the scroll pane.

```
wrapPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(numUnits, 1));
```

On the other hand when you use a GridLayout, then yes all components added to the grid will be resized to the size of the largest component.

So you don't want to use a GridLayout for the wrapper panel.

I would suggest you could use a GridBagLayout or a BoxLayout. As the panel.

Then I would suggest that for your expandable panel you use a BorderLayout. You add the part that is always visible to the CENTER and the expandable part to the PAGE_END. Then when you want to make the panel expand you just change the visibility of the component in the PAGE_END.

Then the layout managers will do all the work recalculating the proper size of the all the panels.

Comment: Thank you camickr! Totally makes sense.  I was looking at the custom panels or the JScrollPanel themselves for the issue when GridLayout was there staring me in my face.  Always great to have a second set of eyes look at these things.  Thanks again!